# Cannot access 'backQueue': it is private in 'NavController'

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

`val queue = navController.backQueue`
`backQueue` becomes private in `androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.6.0-alpha07@aar`

Is there any substitute?

Comment: what do you want to do with backQueue?

Comment: @ZakiShaikh I need to query the navigation history

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you can temporarily access `currentBackStack` in `NavController`.

```kotlin
/**
 * Retrieve the current back stack.
 *
 * @return The current back stack.
 * @hide
 */
@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)
@get:RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)
public val currentBackStack: StateFlow<List<NavBackStackEntry>> =
    _currentBackStack.asStateFlow()
```

Please make sure you read this first: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217465473#comment6 to fully understand the consequences as this API, just like `backQueue`, might not be stable.

Comment: I want to check whether a certain route exists in the navigation heap, how to find it

Comment: `navController.backQueue.filter { it.destination.route == "profileView" }.size == 1` This is the way I'm using now

Comment: `currentBackStack.value` will allow you to access the list underneath which you can filter just like you used to.

Comment: but how to use it? I have this error `NavController.currentBackStack can only be accessed from within the same library group (referenced groupId=androidx.navigation from groupId=MyApp)`

Comment: @tasjapr this only an IDE warning and not a compiler error - it should build fine.